# How to fill a pdf with python

Tags: python, pdf, pdf-writer

I don't have a concrete project yet, but in anticipation I would like to know if it is possible to fill a pdf with data stored in mysql?

It would be a question of a form with several lines and column history not to simplify the thing... If yes, what technology/language to use?

I found several tutorials which however start from a blank pdf. I have the constraint of having to place the data in certain specific places.

Answer (score 0):

Try using PyFPDF or ReportLab to create and manipulate PDF documents in Python.

Answer (score 0):

Using PyMuPDF makes it easy to place text at any desired position using any desired font.

To e.g. put some text on a page starting at position (x, y) do this:

```py
import fitz  # import the package
doc = fitz.open("your.pdf")
page = doc[0]  # desired page, here: page 0
# insert starti 50 points from left, 36 points from top
page insert_text((50, 36), text)  # insert starts here
```

Or insert into a rectangle with automatic line breaks at word boundaries

```py
rect = fitz.Rect(50, 36, 150, 236)  # define rectangle
page.insert_textbox(rect, text)
```

Rectangles are defined by their top-left (50,36) and bottom-right (150, 236) coordinates. So in the above case a 100 x 200 rectangle.

Answer (score 0):

**Disclaimer:** I am the author of `borb`, the library used in this answer.

You are essentially trying to build a customized PDF based on some data.
Let's use the example of generating concert tickets.

1. You have a website that sells tickets,
2. the data ends up in a database,
3. whenever someone wants to print their tickets, you need to build a PDF with their custom data (name, first name, seat numbers, QR code, etc)

There are several things you could do to achieve your goal:

1. Build the PDF from scratch every time
2. Have a template PDF (all the artwork is done, there are some empty slots that can be filled with data)
3. Have a template PDF (all the artwork is done, the PDF contains form elements that can be filled with data)

Option 2 and 3 and typically used in industry, because the people designing the tickets (artwork, layout, etc) are not the people that will write the code needed to build the PDF.

Using `borb`, you can place content at exact locations:

```py
from borb.pdf import Document
from borb.pdf import Page
from borb.pdf import Paragraph
from borb.pdf import PDF
from borb.pdf.canvas.geometry.rectangle import Rectangle

from decimal import Decimal


def main():
    # create Document
    doc: Document = Document()

    # create Page
    page: Page = Page()

    # add Page to Document
    doc.add_page(page)

    # define layout rectangle
    # fmt: off
    r: Rectangle = Rectangle(
        Decimal(59),                # x: 0 + page_margin
        Decimal(848 - 84 - 100),    # y: page_height - page_margin - height_of_textbox
        Decimal(595 - 59 * 2),      # width: page_width - 2 * page_margin
        Decimal(100),               # height
    )
    # fmt: on

    # the next line of code uses absolute positioning
    Paragraph("Hello World!").paint(page, r)

    # store
    with open("output.pdf", "wb") as pdf_file_handle:
        PDF.dumps(pdf_file_handle, doc)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

You can also fill forms:

```py
from decimal import Decimal

from borb.pdf import HexColor
from borb.pdf import PageLayout
from borb.pdf import Document
from borb.pdf import Page
from borb.pdf import PDF


def main():

    # open document
    doc: typing.Optional[Document] = None
    with open("output.pdf", "rb") as pdf_file_handle:
        doc = PDF.loads(pdf_file_handle)
    assert doc is not None

    # set
    doc.get_page(0).set_form_field_value("name", "Schellekens")
    doc.get_page(0).set_form_field_value("firstname", "Joris")
    doc.get_page(0).set_form_field_value("country", "Belgium")

    # store
    with open("output.pdf", "wb") as pdf_file_handle:
        PDF.dumps(pdf_file_handle, doc)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```